# Bootstrap Tooltip Not Showing Up in MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In an MVC5 application, I'm trying to add Bootstrap tooltips to an input element. I did this by defining a custom helper class:

```
public static class CustomHtmlHelpers
{
    public static string DescriptionFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> self, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, self.ViewData);
        var description = metadata.Description;

        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(description) ? "" : description;
    }
}
```

And adding a Description attribute to my model:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}")]
[Display(Name = "Total Annual Spend", Description = "Total annual cost of this plan.")]
public decimal AnnualSpend { get; set; }
```

I first made sure I could use my helper class to properly pull the description value by creating a div with @Html.DescriptionFor(); it displayed properly.

Now I'm trying to add the tooltip with:

```
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnnualSpend, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnnualSpend, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", rel="txtTooltip", data_toggle = "tooltip", data_placement = "bottom", title = Html.DescriptionFor(model => model.AnnualSpend) } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnnualSpend, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
```

And the script:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[rel="txtTooltip"]').tooltip();
        });
```

The script fires, [I can see it in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VaDi.png), but no tooltip is being displayed. This probably doesn't make a difference, but the form is housed in a Partial View.

Here's the rendered HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
                <label class="control-label" for="model_db94d00a-edbb-47d7-a153-d90b47d35e13__AnnualSpend">Total Annual Spend</label>

                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Total Annual Spend must be a number." data-val-required="The Total Annual Spend field is required." id="model_db94d00a-edbb-47d7-a153-d90b47d35e13__AnnualSpend" name="model[db94d00a-edbb-47d7-a153-d90b47d35e13].AnnualSpend" rel="txtTooltip" title="" type="text" value="" data-original-title="Total annual cost of this plan.">
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="model[db94d00a-edbb-47d7-a153-d90b47d35e13].AnnualSpend" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
```

On hover, the [tooltip is being appended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqs2q.png). I tried removing the field label, but the tooltip still didn't display.

Why isn't it displaying? I've reviewed a number of other posts here without finding an answer.

Comment: show your rendered html output

Comment: Have noticed the generated HTML markup ? `title=""` Is that expected ?

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't noticed that. The proper title is in the element "data-original-title," but I'm not sure if that's where it belongs.

Comment: FYI, title="the correct title" until a user hovers over the field, at which point title="" and data_original_title="the correct title"

Comment: something else is happening, your code works as expected for me, with bootstrap-3

Comment: @mxmissile Thank you so much for your comment. I discovered the issue. I was using bootstrap.js version 4.x.x and bootstrap.css version 3.x.x.